# list-box selection event error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nullreferenceexception

I am using list-box to select a item from list box but as i select it it generates an underhanded exception.Here my code is:
`

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1"  SelectionChanged="PrintText" Background="DarkGray" Visibility="Collapsed"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,36,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" UseLayoutRounding="True" />

 void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
            String a =  lbi.Content.ToString();
           Window1 neww = null;
            neww = new Window1();
            neww.Show();
        }
```

` i don't know where i am doing mistake please guide me. I have attached image of it to make you more clear. [image]thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  object item = listBox1.SelectedItem;

  if (item == null) {
    txtSelectedItem.Text = "No item currently selected.";
  } else {
    txtSelectedItem.Text = item.ToString();
  }

  // ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
  //  String a =  lbi.Content.ToString();
  Window1 neww = null;
  neww = new Window1();
  neww.Show();
}
```

Comment: if this is your answer, then kindly choose it as answer, so no one else will have to read your entire problem again